# Intuit Anywhere disconnect

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am in the final stages of implementing my Intuit Anywhere app but have failed one of the test (Disconnect).

The user has authorized my application.  If the user logs into Intuit Anywhere and disconnects from my application via "Manage My Apps" I get a

```
"Confirm Disconnect" popup window that says "You have successfully disconnected from
MyApp for QuickBooks. Click "Next" to go to MyApp for QuickBooks to confirm this
action."
```

When I click on next I am brought to my login screen instead of the URL specified as the "Disconnect Landing URL".

```
Name of App:                My App for QuickBooks
App URL:                    https://mydomain.com/Login.aspx
Disconnect Landing URL:     https://mydomain.com/Disconnected.aspx
Manage Users URL:           https://mydomain.com/Login.aspx
OpenID URL:                 https://mydomain.com/Login.aspx
Host Name Domain:           mydomain.com
Data Source:                QuickBooks Online
```

Why am I not brought to the Disconnected page? How am I to "confirm this action"?

Thoughts?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

An openId assertion is sent to the disconnect landing page its not a redirect.

thanks
Jarred

Comment: Curious - what if you're not using OpenID? Is there a way to handle this then?

Comment: If they disconnect from within your app then you will know which user/realm. If they are not logged into your site and go to Intuit and disconnect you would need to implement openid to get the openid, email and realm.

Comment: What does the OpenID assertion mean? I can't find this anywhere in the doc. Is this a payload sent as a parameter to the disconnect method?